# Can genes that activate transcription factors also called be called transcription factors?

Tags: genetics, transcription

If the sole known function of a gene is to activate a transcription factor, would that gene also be considered a transcription factor, or is there a word for such genes that are further upstream on the transcription activation cascade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  For an example, see [this list of targets of NF-kB](http://www.bu.edu/nf-kb/gene-resources/target-genes/) (a transcription factor).  Many other transcription factors are included there.  As for a TF that does *nothing* except activate another, *single* TF?  I don't know that those exist - TFs tend to modulate multiple genes.

Answer (score 5):

From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_factor) article on TFs:

> In molecular biology and genetics, a transcription factor (sometimes called a sequence-specific DNA-binding factor) is a protein that binds to specific DNA sequences, thereby controlling the flow (or transcription) of genetic information from DNA to messenger RNA.

The nature of the gene affected is irrelevant, a protein is a transcription factor if it binds to a gene's promoter and regulates that gene's transcription. Whether the regulated gene also codes for a TF does not enter into it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to re-write your question, it is ambiguous and your use of terms is incorrect... Assumption: by "activation" you mean "activation of transcription resulting in the expression of the transcription factor"

1) Transcription factors are proteins

2) Genes are comprised of DNA elements

A transcription factor can be involved in initiating the EXPRESSION of a transcription factor, whereafter that second distinct transcription factor initiates the EXPRESSION of another gene that encodes another transcription factor.

Answer: No, genes do not "activate" transcription factors*

*Unless you are proposing the philosophical question of whether the DNA binding domain itself, which endows the transcription factor with a state of being active duty (i.e. fulfilling its purpose as a transcription factor), and thus that purpose is fulfilled only when the DNA binds the the TF, then a DNA binding domain can indeed "activate" the TF... but I'm pretty sure this isn't what you're asking.

Comment: I simply meant to ask whether there was another term for a transcription factor upstream on the activation pathway of another transcription factor. Does that make more sense?